# Why OpenCV versions are different in dpkg and pkg-config

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, opencv3.0, dpkg, pkg-config

In the terminal,

I got `3.1.0` from `pkg-config --modversion opencv`

However, from `dpkg -l | grep libopencv`
all opencv related packages' version are `2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1`

Do I make any mistake when building OpenCV from resource or it is correct?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pkg-config --modversion opencv` will tell you about the libraries that you installed by downloading the tarball from [opencv](http://opencv.org/downloads.html) or using `git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git` followed by **`cmake`** or `make install`. You can check them in `/usr/local/include/opencv` or `/usr/local/include/opencv2` in most of the cases.

`dpkg -l | grep libopencv` will show the version of library installed using dpkg or any other package manager.

If you do **`git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git`** most likely it will download the **3.x** version of libraries while installation with package manager may contain old versions of opencv libraries

Comment: Thank you so much for precious time on my question!

Comment: And is it bad, that I have two versions? 2.4.8 and 3.1.0? I hope opencv uses 3.1.0

Comment: on linux you can use commands like `which opencv` which will tell the path of `opencv` executables

Comment: If you install other packages (using apt-get, apt, etc) that are dependant on opencv, they will be linked to the dpkg version.  *I hope opencv uses 3.1.0*... it is another program that will use opencv.  They should be linked against the appropriate version.  If the version is explicit, they will not be mixed up.  Ie, there are symlinks from minor versions of the libraries.